# Sliding Window generates more events than original input

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-processing, complex-event-processing

**Input data:** `{ticker: 'MSFT', price: 100}`

**Queries:**

```
SELECT * INTO [originalInput] FROM [eventhub-input] /* 341 rows*/
SELECT * INTO [window20Output] FROM window20 /* 676 rows */
SELECT * INTO [window10Output] FROM window10 /* 673 rows */
SELECT * INTO [window5Output] FROM window5 /* 672 rows */
SELECT * INTO [window3Output] FROM window3 /* 674 rows */
```

The windows are `SlidingWindows` and **Grouped By** `ticker`

**The issue here is that my windows do not generate the same number of rows**

My goal is them generating the same number of rows at the same time so I can JOIN them all and create a single output.

So what is the issue here ?

Thanks

Comment: Using Sliding windows, your query will output every time an event occurs. So each window could result in a different count. Can you explain your goal by giving an example of detailed input and output you expect?

Comment: If I receive let's say 100 events from my original input, I'm expecting to see 100 events coming out from the SlidingWindows since they emit everytime a new event comes in.

Comment: One event could be part of 2 or more sliding windows depending on the window size and also the type of operations you seek to perform on the data. This link describes this behavior very well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions

Comment: As Sid mentioned in earlier comment, sliding window just looks back events until provided time. It has no conditions on the number of events. If you would like to have control over number of events, CollectTop() is an option. However note that this is maximum number of events, not exact number of events.